# Entity Data Model Wizard is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

in VS2012 i'm trying to update model from database, but my Entity Data Model Wizard is not showing and I cant choose connection, it only shows the next step after choosing connection : that is choosing to add, refresh or delete tables.

Any ideas how to return my wizard back on step choosing connection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show screen shots of what you are doing ? at what point you want to go one step back ?

Note: i am writing this as an answer because i can't post comment at this time.

Comment: Hello, I want to choose between different connection strings, but now I get this window(in my question) and by back button is inactive:

Comment: That window is update wizard which you get once your EF setup is done. Make sure you are selecting **generate EF using Database** option.
can you show what you see when
right click on soultion
select add > new item > ADO.net Entity Data Model 
now select create entity framework with database
n show me what you see there

Comment: i don't think you can change your connection once it's setup is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install template that will generate simple POCO entity classes. Try to install DbContextGenerator  like EF 6.x DbContextGenerator

```
EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C#
EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C# Web Sites
EF 4.x DbContext Generator for VB.NET
EF 4.x DbContext Generator for VB.NET Web Sites
```